# Appengine Java: NotSerializableException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, serialization

i developed an application in GAE Java, but i'm getting an error **only on deployed version**, i'm unable to ricreate the condition on local environment.

When i call a servlet i've made, the process ends w/o any error (i logged a lot the all procedure in order to fix this problem). The servlet prints the response output and then the code is finished.

But after this procedure i'm getting the following error, so the real response received by the client is a classic Error 500 page.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.serialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:31)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.createEntityForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:72)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:94)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:156)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1197)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1545)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1191)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:363)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1191)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:363)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.serialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:28)
    ... 32 more
```

I already read [in this page](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1056757) that this is a commun mistake because Logger is not serializable, so i declare all Loggers in my project as

```
final static transient Logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

But still no solution....
It is all day i'm trying to fix this problem (and the fact that is only a problem on deployed version is not helping...)

I also need to clarify that 2 weeks ago the deployed version worked perfectly, w/o any problems. Today, the same version, starts to work with errors like explained.
I'm wondering if the cause might be the new released version of GAE 1.8.0

Thanks for your support
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved the question using this "trick" in every class that use Log

```
public Logger log()
{
    return Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName());
}
```

and then in the class, where log is needed, i used

```
log().info(...);
log().severe(...);
....
```

With this procedure, the class does not store an object Logger, so during the serialization does not try to serialize the Logger object